# richFaces fileUploadListener not getting called at all

Tags: file-upload, richfaces

I am using richfaces fileUpload to upload a xls file. below is the code rich modal panel used for the uploading thing

```
<rich:modalPanel id="cashflowImportPanel" width="360" height="150"
                zindex="500" autosized="true">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Confirm" />
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="controls">
                     <h:graphicImage value="../../static/images/close.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('cashflowImportPanel')"  />     
                </f:facet>

            <h:panelGroup id="cashflowimportpanelGrp">

                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle['cashflowImportSupportedFiles.label']}" />                    

                        <rich:fileUpload 
                        maxFilesQuantity="1" 
                        immediateUpload="true" 
                        acceptedTypes="xls"
                        id="fileUploadComp" 
                        listHeight="63px" 
                        listWidth="350px"
                        fileUploadListener="#{fileImportBean.importFile}"
                        uploadData="#{fileImportBean.uploadedData}" 
                        allowFlash="false">
                        <a4j:support 
                        event="onclear" 
                        action="#{fileImportBean.importFile}" 
                        />
                       </rich:fileUpload>
            <rich:spacer height="30"/>

                <s:selectOneMenuAjax
                 prop="selectedForecastMonth"
                 key="forecastMonthForImport" 
                 bean="#{cflowForecastBean.cashflowForecast}"
                 id="forecastMonthIdForImport" 
                 selectItems="#{cflowForecastBean.forecastMonth}" 
                 req="true"
                 actionBean="#{cflowForecastBean}" 
                 method="getForecastCycleMonth" 
                 />                         
                <a4j:commandButton 
                    id="importBtn"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('cashflowImportPanel')}.hide();"
                    action="#{fileImportBean.saveFileExportImport}"
                    value="#{bundle['import.label']}"
                    styleClass="button"
                    status="waitStatus" 
                    reRender="importBtn,msgPanelGrp">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="xls"
                                target="#{fileImportBean.importFileType}" />
                        </a4j:commandButton>
                <a4j:commandButton
                            onclick="#{rich:component('cashflowImportPanel')}.hide();"
                            value="#{bundle['no.label']}" 
                            styleClass="button"
                            immediate="true" />

            </h:panelGroup>

    </rich:modalPanel>
```

and bean

```
public void importFile(UploadEvent event) {
    --------
}
```

However i the fileUploadListener is not getting called at all. I use richFaces 3.3.1 and tomcat 6.X server. Also this same functionality is working fine in other parts of my project but not working in this case only.can anyone help?

Comment: What version of RichFaces and what server do you use?

Comment: @Makhiel  I use richFaces 3.3.1 and tomcat 6.X server. Also this same functionality is working fine in other parts of my project but not working in this case only. something is wrong on this page i am not getting what i am missing

Comment: Try without `uploadData="#{fileImportBean.uploadedData}"`